# screenshot java code in appium selenium

Tags: java, android, appium

Can anyone advice me what should be the screenshot capture code for AndroidDriver. I am using below code for which i am getting Java null pointer exception for the highlighted line.

Driver is a AndroidDriver  driver; which is extended to this class.

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(!result.isSuccess()){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");

        String methodName = result.getName();


        ****File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);****
        try {
            String reportDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath() + "\\src\\test\\java\\com\\automation\\mobile\\app\\android\\";
            File destFile = new File((String) reportDirectory + "/failure_screenshots/" + methodName + "_" + formater.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".png");

            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);

            Reporter.log("<a href='" + destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'> <img src='" + destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "' height='100' width='100'/> </a>");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created driver something like this:

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

You can create a screenshot simply doing:

```
    File srcFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File targetFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/screenshots/" + filename + ".jpg");
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, targetFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Just make sure your driver session is still alive before you are making screenshot -> check appium server logs, you might got 500 and then it failed to take screenshot

Tested on **appium 1.8** and **java-client 6.0.0-BETA5**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution in C#. Translating to Java shouldn't be too complicated

Here screenshotName is the name you want your file to have, and driver is your driver instance piloting your appium.

```
public void GetScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, string screenshotName)
{
    ITakesScreenshot ts = (ITakesScreenshot) driver;

    var screenshot = ts.GetScreenshot();
    var screenshotPath = @"C:\temp\" + screenshotName +".bmp";

    screenshot.SaveAsFile(screenshotPath);
}
```

Hope this helps !